# A JSON message published to SNS doesn't trigger the Consumer (lambda func)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, queue, amazon-sqs

I have three lambda questions:

- interceptor: gets queries and publishes the payload to SNS
- classifier: gets the payload and classifies it into one category1 (or other categories)
- category1: gets the payload and processes it

I have 1 SNS topic, and each lambda has its own SQS queue. I also have one standard way of publishing to SNS:

```py
def publish_message_to_sns(message: Dict[str, Any], 
                           topic_name: str, 
                           message_group_id: str, 
                           message_attributes: Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    # Serialize the message to JSON
    json_message = json.dumps({
        "default": json.dumps(message),
    })    
    print("Publishing to SNS: ", json_message)
    print("message_group_id: ", message_group_id)
    # sns is a boto3 client for SNS
    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn=get_topic_arn(topic_name),
        Message=json_message,
        MessageGroupId=message_group_id,
        MessageStructure='json',
        MessageAttributes=message_attributes
    )
    return response
```

In the `interceptor` lambda:

```py
    topic_arn = get_topic_arn("MyTopic.fifo")

    message_attributes = {
        'category': {
        'DataType': 'String',
        'StringValue': 'to_classify'
        }
    }
    response = publish_message_to_sns(body, topic_arn, 'to_classify' ,message_attributes)
```

When this is executed, it triggers the `classifier` lambda function as expected, which in turn at some point executes this:

```py
    message_attributes = {
        'category': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': 'category1'
        }
    }
    response = publish_message_to_sns(
        message, topic_name, 'category1', message_attributes)
```

However, this doesn't trigger the `category1` lambda function, which is the problem. I want to go through the AWS setup of the SQS queues and SNS topic; it's good. The SQS queues have similar configs, and the trigger lambdas are well configured.

I look into the logs to see if the messages are stringified differently, but they have the same structure across different lambdas because we use the same function to publish and the same logic, which is uniform. But I don't understand why the `category1` lambda function isn't triggered...

**EDIT**:
For clarification and to answer John's questions, I have configured the Amazon SQS queue (for category1) to have the SNS Topic as a subscription, and the Lambda function (category1) is configured with the same SQS Queue (for category1) as a lambda trigger.
Using the AWS Console, when I go to the SNS Queue page, on "Send and receive messages", and send a dummy message, I can see the lambda triggered via CloudWatch logs.
I would also like to mention that the publisher (`classifier`) successfully publishes to the SNS according to the CloudWatch logs and I can see the response from the SNS topic in the logs (with the `SequenceNumber`, `MessageId`, etc)

**EDIT 2**
I realized something *very* weird:

- in one publisher (`interceptor` lambda function): the code I use to publish:

```
def publish_message_to_sns(message: Dict[str, Any], 
                           topic_name: str, 
                           message_group_id: str, 
                           message_attributes: Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    # Serialize the message to JSON
    json_message = json.dumps({
        "default": json.dumps(message),  # Ensure message is a serialized string for the 'default' key
    })    
    print("Publishing to SNS: ", json_message)
    print("message_group_id: ", message_group_id)
    # sns is a boto3 client for SNS
    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn=get_topic_arn(topic_name),
        Message=json_message,
        MessageGroupId=message_group_id,
        MessageStructure='json',
        MessageAttributes=message_attributes
    )
    return response
```

- in my other publisher (`classifier` lambda function), which picks up from its own queue, I got this code!

```py
response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn=get_topic_arn(topic_name),  # Ensure this function returns the correct ARN as a string
        # Message=json_message,
        Message=message,
        MessageGroupId=message_group_id,
        # MessageStructure='json',
        MessageAttributes=message_attributes
    )
```

Now, it works, but my question is WHY? The setup is the same on the console, I checked many times. Doesn't this have to do with the fact that `interceptor` gets incoming API queries and is the *first* publisher to SNS?

Comment: You appear to be saying that your problem is that publishing a message to an Amazon SNS Topic is not resulting in an AWS Lambda function being invoked. Are you sure that the Lambda function has been configured with the SNS Topic as a Trigger? Or have you configured an Amazon SQS queue as a subscriber on the SNS Topic and the Lambda function is configured with the SQS Queue as a trigger? If so, when you manually send a message to the SQS Queue (without going via SNS), does it trigger the Lambda function? Please Edit your Question to clarify the flow of messages.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I have edited the question with an EDIT section at the end; I hope that clarifies the context

Comment: So you're saying that manually sending a message to the SNS Topic successfully triggers the 'category1' Lambda function, but your 3rd code sample that sends a message to the same SNS queue does _not_ trigger the Lambda function? Did you add some debug code to view the exact parameters it used, to verify it's the same as the manual test? (eg `print(message, topic_name, message_attributes)`)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein:  I got it working, but I still don't understand the differences / the why. You can check my EDIT2